# How to install mssql in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu-14.04

I want to install mssql with 2008/2012.Please suggest proper doc or steps to install.I have try to instaall from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-ubuntu but it give me follwoing error -

```
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsss_nss_idmap.so.0: no version information available (required by /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr)
Starting Microsoft SQL Server...
sudo: systemctl: command not found
Error starting Microsoft SQL Server.
```

while run command -

> sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use systemctl in Ubuntu 14.04](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37438630/how-to-use-systemctl-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: @Parita did you find a workaround? To make mssql work in ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 4):

you can't install mssql in ubuntu 14.04..[Docs clearly state supported versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup)

> SQL Server vNext CTP 2.0 is supported on the following platforms:

[image]

Just to add ,I thought installing docker would support versions less than 16,but from [docker file](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/blob/master/linux/preview/Ubuntu/Dockerfile) we could see below

> Base OS layer: Latest Ubuntu LTS.
>   FROM ubuntu:16.04

which means it needs ubuntu:16.04 versions to be present

Answer (score 2):

For a workaround, you can use run a Docker container ([`microsoft/mssql-server-linux`](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux/)), e.g.

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=yourStrongPassword!" -p 1433:1433 microsoft/mssql-server-linux
```

Then connect to `localhost:1433` with your SQL client.

Answer (score 0):

You can't because You must have 16.04+ Ubuntu version to install  MSSQL according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to instal sql server 2008 or 2012 on any non window platform.
This feature came with 2016 or 2017.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2017

Comment: so you mean to say that we download 2016 or 2017 in ubuntu??